# Yii widget ECKEditor not working on

Tags: php, yii

I have implemented ECKEditor on multiple forms in my Yii application. Everywhere works besides one page. This is the code I am using:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'my-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'action' => array("//path-to-this-file/"),
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'form-horizontal'),
    ));
?>

<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.eckeditor.ECKEditor', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'details',
)); ?>

 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Don't know with might be the cause, but I see two possibilities:

- I get the following error in Web Console:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]

- Could something be wrong with the model on that page? Since it's the only page where it's not working.

Comment: update  .. your question and add also the code before and after the widget

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge , code updated